# Highstock grouping show hidden serie values in tooltip

Tags: javascript, highcharts

We have a chart with 3 series, one of them hidden. It uses highstock grouping feature. In the tooltip we want to show the values for the 3 series, but the one that is hidden doesn't calculates the values grouped.

On tooltip callback:
This not hidden series returns grouped values:

```
item.chart.series[1].processedYData
```

But with the hidden series it returns all values:

```
item.chart.series[2].processedYData
```

Is there a way to make highcharts process also series with visible=false, or to call some method so it will return the correct value for a point?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can make the series invisible by disabling its mouse event and set color to none. The series will be processed and you gain access to the data.

```
series: [{
  name: 's1',
  data: [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
}, {
  name: 's2',
  data: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
}, {
  name: 's3',
  data: [-2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2],
  enabledMouseTracking: false,
  color: 'none'
}]
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/a0p7h777/

If you want the hidden series to not affect axis scale then you can link it to a hidden axis.

```
    yAxis: [{

},{
  visible: false
}],

{
  name: 's3',
  data: [-2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2],
  enabledMouseTracking: false,
  color: 'none',
  yAxis: 1
}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/a0p7h777/1/